# AWS GlueJob Error - Command failed with exit code 137

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am executing a AWS-Gluejob with python shell. It fails inconsistently with the error "*Command failed with exit code 137*" and executes perfectly fine with no changes sometimes.

What does this error signify? Are there any changes we can do in the job configuration to handle the same?

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWh54.png)

Comment: Exit code 137 means that your process was killed by (signal 9) SIGKILL . In the case you manually stopped it - there's your answer. If you didn't manually stop the script and still got this error code, then the script was killed by your OS. In most of the cases, it is caused by excessive memory usage

Comment: Thank you @Ali. But the issue I am facing is that the job does not event start. Is it possible that the memory is used up by other jobs?

Comment: AWS Glue set up executor's instance with memory limit to 5 GB is your file larger ?

Comment: Also you can define the worker type now https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/glue/latest/dg/add-job.html

Comment: Not really, But in that case, the process would not have been able to run other times right? Is the 5 GB limit on only one process or all of the glue job processes for that account?

Comment: For each tuple (customer account ID, IAM role, subnet ID, and security group), AWS Glue creates a new Spark environment

Comment: Thanks @Ali! Setting the appropriate worker type helped!

Comment: How do you set the WorkerType? I got an error message saying that WorkerType is not supported by pythonshell jobs.
    "Worker Type is not supported for Job Command pythonshell (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInputException;"

Comment: Add the worker type under the 'Job Parameters' under 'Security configuration, script libraries, and job parameters'. For Example: Set Key as 'WorkerType' and Value as G.2X="". Although, it still seems to be restricted as 5GB for one IAM Role.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the worker type to the Job Properties will resolve the issue.Based on the file size please select the worker type as below:

- Standard – When you choose this type, you also provide a value for Maximum capacity. Maximum capacity is the number of AWS Glue data processing units (DPUs) that can be allocated when this job runs. A DPU is a relative measure of processing power that consists of 4 vCPUs of compute capacity and 16 GB of memory. The Standard worker type has a 50 GB disk and 2 executors.
- G.1X – When you choose this type, you also provide a value for Number of workers. Each worker maps to 1 DPU (4 vCPU, 16 GB of memory, 64 GB disk), and provides 1 executor per worker. We recommend this worker type for memory-intensive jobs.
- G.2X – When you choose this type, you also provide a value for Number of workers. Each worker maps to 2 DPU (8 vCPU, 32 GB of memory, 128 GB disk), and provides 1 executor per worker. We recommend this worker type for memory-intensive jobs and jobs that run ML transforms.